# MVC Ajax alert not working properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My alert() is not showing after posting...

When I submit my form, I see the data posted, and all looks good, but the  alert('ok');   from ajax does not show up.  what am I missing?

```
@model Mvc5.Models.Test

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" id="idForm" />

}

<div id="target">
@Html.Action("ShowList", "Test")
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // this is the id of the form
        $("#idForm").submit(function () {

            var url = "Test/Create"; // the script where you handle the form input.

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');                
                }
            });

            return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: have you checked the status..??

Comment: Maybe you don't return object with property "success" from your action? Did you try to debug success js handler?

Comment: @user1929393 check your browser's developer console for error message and also check status of the POST request to "Test/Create"

Comment: I updated it to not check status.. but alert still not showing up.

Comment: Can you show what is the value of data in Success of ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should validate form before submit to controller, see below code

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $("input#submitForm").click(function () {
                if ($('#myForm').valid()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/controllerName/ActionName",
                        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
                        success: function (result) {
                           alert('sucess');
                        }
                    });

                } return false;
            });
```

and dont forget to include the validation scripts

```
src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
```

Also return json from controller

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
  return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: what is this? Is it the id for the submit button?  input#submitForm   Also, don't you need a way to process the json if you are returning json?  I've tried this, but when I post, the page just shows json result and rest of page does not load.

Answer (score 0):

Add Error as shown below and see which alert message is being displayed. You can also add debugger and developer tool to debug the same.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
  success: function (result, status) {
    if (status == 'success') {
      if (result.success) {
        OnSuccessActions();
      } else {
        $('.ValidationSummary').html(result.Error);
      }
    }
  },   
  error: function() {
   alert('error!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your success func is going to run if your ajax request receives a 200 status code back from your api. I'd double check to make sure that is happening.

edit.

You should also prevent the form from doing a server postback since you are making an ajax call.

```
$("#idForm").submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var url = "Test/Create"; // the script where you handle the form input.
```